# Issue with calculating the visible area of a zoomed image in a PictureBox in C#

Tags: c#, graphics, imagemagick, picturebox

I'm having trouble calculating the visible area of a zoomed image in a PictureBox control in C#. Specifically, I'm trying to calculate a `RectangleF` that identifies the visible portion of the image within the `PictureBox`, based on the `scaledRect` (which specifies the position and size of the zoomed image within the PictureBox), the `zoomFactor` (which represents the zoom level applied), the size of the PictureBox and the size of the original Image.

I need after to map this RectangleF to the size of the original image.

I've tried a few different approaches, but I haven't been able to get it to work correctly. I've tried this code:

```
//Calculates the position of the upper left corner of the visible area
    PointF zoomedTopLeft = new PointF(
        (_pictureBox.Width - scaledRect.Width) / 2f - scaledRect.X,
        (_pictureBox.Height - scaledRect.Height) / 2f - scaledRect.Y
    );
    
    // Calculates the size of the visible area of the zoomed image
    float zoomedWidth = _pictureBox.Width / zoomFactor;
    float zoomedHeight = _pictureBox.Height / zoomFactor;
    
    // Convert the coordinates of the upper left corner and the size of the visible area from the zoomed image to the original image
    float visibleLeft = zoomedTopLeft.X / zoomFactor;
    float visibleTop = zoomedTopLeft.Y / zoomFactor;
    float visibleWidth = zoomedWidth / zoomFactor;
    float visibleHeight = zoomedHeight / zoomFactor;
    
    RectangleF visibleRect = new RectangleF(
        visibleLeft, visibleTop, visibleWidth, visibleHeight
    );
```

Someone knows how to do?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I found this solution that it's working for me.

```
private RectangleF GetVisibleRectangle(RectangleF scaledRect) {


            RectangleF imageRect = scaledRect;
            imageRect.Intersect(_containerClientSize);

            float offsetX = 0;
            float offsetY = 0; 

            return new RectangleF(
                (imageRect.X - scaledRect.X + offsetX) / _zoomFactor,
                (imageRect.Y - scaledRect.Y + offsetY) / _zoomFactor,
                imageRect.Width / _zoomFactor,
                imageRect.Height / _zoomFactor
            );


        }
```